# How to change InnerHTML of all the buttons in one go in HTML using jQuery and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose, I have 5 buttons on my page. How can I change the innerHTML of the buttons in one go. I buttons having text "Clicked" should get changed to "Click me" when Change InnerHTML button is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeInnerHTML()
        {
            //Iterate all the buttons with innerHTML = "Clicked" in the DOM and set them to "Click me".
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="myButton1">Click me</button>
    <button type="button" id="myButton2">Clicked</button>
    <button type="button" id="myButton3">Click me</button>
    <button type="button" id="myButton4">Clicked</button>
    <button type="button" id="myButton5">Click me</button>

    <button type="button" id="btnChangeInnerHTML" onclick="ChangeInnerHTML()">Change InnerHTML</button>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you have tagged the question using jQuery but is it not used?

Comment: @ArunPJohny - I think it can be done using jQuery. Earlier I had emptied all my textboxes using jquery like this $('input[type=text]').val("");. But this time I have to change innerHTML of some of the buttons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
function ChangeInnerHTML() {
    $('button').each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).html()) == "Clicked") 
            $(this).html('Click me');
    });
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xxPKy/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use Attribute selector in jquery.

```
function ChangeInnerHTML() {
           $("[id^=myButton]:contains('Clicked')").click(function() {
                     $(this).text("Click Me");

        });
       }
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/xxPKy/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Without jQuery

```
function ChangeInnerHTML() {
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button[id^=myButton]');
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        if (btns[i].innerHTML.trim() == 'Clicked') {
            btns[i].innerHTML = 'Click Me'
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zkBLW/)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers look like too much work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeInnerHTML(){
            document.body.innerHTML=
            document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Clicked/g,'Click me');
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="myButton1">Click me</button>
    <button type="button" id="myButton2">Clicked</button>
    <button type="button" id="myButton3">Click me</button>
    <button type="button" id="myButton4">Clicked</button>
    <button type="button" id="myButton5">Click me</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnChangeInnerHTML" onclick="ChangeInnerHTML()">Change InnerHTML</button>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ChangeInnerHTML()
{
    $("button[id*=myButton]").html("Click me");
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the html of all the buttons.

Comment: this only changes for buttons containing "myButton" in their id attribute. for more information, look up the jquery selectors page at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: The button whose html is Clicked, only those should get changed to Click me. Your code will change the html of all the buttons containing myButton id.

Comment: you do realise that changing "Click me" to "Click me" has no effect

Comment: But why to change "Click me" to "Click me" as it does not make any sense. Also I have some other buttons in my page for some other purpose whose id starts from "myButton". Those will also get affected by above approach.